# Krylov space, linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I have some arbitrary matrix $A$, now I want to build Krylov space $\mathbb{K} = \{ q , Aq, A^2 q , ... , A^{n-1} q \}$. Now, is there a way of chosing vector $q$ so that $q , A^q , ... A^{n-1} q$ are linearly independent? I can always state the hypothesis that some $q_0$ satisfies this requirement, if not I can pick different $q_1$ and check again, and so on, but I want to know if there is some different approach.
Second question: what requirements should $A$ satisfy, so that there exists such $q$ that $q , Aq, A^2 q , ... , A^{n-1} q$ are linearly independent?

Comment: What is $n$? The order of $A$ or just arbitrary?

Comment: should've specified that $n$ denotes dimention of $A$, meaning $A$ is matrix $n \times n$

Comment: Second question has a [simple answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix#Characterization).